# Community builder can not read property 'def' of undefined

Tags: community, community-builder

I have extracted the metadata of a community from one sandbox, (network, site and siteDotCom and all other relevant such as Lightning components) and have deployed them with ant in another sandbox.
When I go to the newly created community in the target sandbox and try to access the builder the following error occurs in chrome:
[image]

if I click close, the builder is loading indefinitely.
The error in firefox and safari is a little more detailed:
[image]

So far I have tried the following but nothing resolved the issue
- Flushing my cache
- Different browsers
- Publishing the community and trying again
- Renaming the community to remove any spaces from the name
- Searching for the term 'Branding' and 'def' in the metadata deployed, nothing appears
- Trying to find the custom branding, can not edit it as the builder loads indefinitely.

Any suggestions ?

Answer (score 1):

I ran into the same issue deploying Community Metadata. The only solution I have found so far is to first create a blank community in the target org matching the name and url of the one you want to deploy. After if I only deployed the necessary Network, NetworkBranding, CustomSite, SiteDotCom, custom Lightning Components, and any custom Apex Class Controllers metadata, then I was able to view the builder for the community in target org.

Hopefully this helps!

Comment: Thanks @kgutierrez! We resolved it by refreshing our sandbox and thus getting the community from the Production org. Then we deployed the changed components with no issue of the community builder. The builder is a still clunky, I think there are a few improvements that should take place.